# Airflow change variable value in DAG with external parameter

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to change variable value defined in DAG(DAG_1) with the value received from external DAG(DAG_2).

The idea is to have default value of variable 'NAME' inside DAG_1 but if supplied from external DAG replace it's value. I'm able successfully pull in DAG_1 all the externally supplied parameters but cannot change value of variable NAME.
DAG_1:

```
NAME = 'Stream_Agg_DIL_Dev_Airflow '
....
def set_config(ds, **kwargs):
   PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = DMP_ROOT+ kwargs['dag_run'].conf['config']
   NAME = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']
   return PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH, NAME

def get_pull(ds, **kwargs):
   ti = kwargs['ti']
   global NAME
   NAME1 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_config_param', key='NAME')
   print('NAME1 = ' + NAME1 + ', NAME = ' + NAME)
   NAME = NAME1
   print('NAME1 = ' + NAME1 + ', NAME = ' + NAME)
```

on second print, inside function NAME and NAME1 are the same, but printing NAME from other pythonOperator gets original value:

```
NAME = 'Stream_Agg_DIL_Dev_Airflow '
```

Comment: I don't think you can pull the correct variables from the task instance, because as far as I understood it, a DAG holds one/ several task instances but DAGs do not communicate. A `global` variable will be available in every task instance on its own since every task is newly instanciated afaik. Also, it is not clear what you mean with pythonOperator and how your DAG_2 looks like,

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to perform the same thing

```
messages = []

def pull_function(**context):
    global messages
    print(messages)
    messages = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='fetch_data')
    print(messages)


def check_function():
    print(messages)
```

In pull_function first it print [ ] next it print {
            'name': 'name',
            'email': 'email',
            'mobile': '123214564',
            'event': '654646464'
        } but in check_function again it print [ ]